# To edit multiple record at once in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to bulk edit of records. I am using form collection for this method.

I am currently loop through all items and use the GetValues method to store all the items into array.

I don't want to do this way because if my list gets bigger then it could be slowing things down. So what is it that I need to do to make my array/list smaller so it only store what has changed?

Thanks

Here is my controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection c)
    {
        int i = 0;
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var ProductIDArray = c.GetValues("item.Id");
            var ProductReviewStatus = c.GetValues("item.ReviewStatus");

            for (i = 0; i < ProductIDArray.Count(); i++)
            {
                ProductViewModel prod = db.Product.Find(Convert.ToInt32(ProductIDArray[i]));
                prod.ReviewStatus = (StatusOfReview)Enum.Parse(typeof(StatusOfReview), ProductReviewStatus[i], true);
                db.Entry(prod).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
        //return View(db.Product.ToList());
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

And here is my View

```
    @model IEnumerable<Test_ListDrop.Models.ProductViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Cost)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OutOfStock)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ReviewStatus)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cost)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OutOfStock)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => item.ReviewStatus, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.ReviewStatus, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
}
```

Comment: have a look here, it might help: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1191769/Beginners-Guide-for-implementing-AJAX-CRUD-Operati

Comment: thanks. using IPagedList seems to be the solution

Comment: quick question. how do I set default value of DropDownListFor to be the value selected in database?

I am currently doing this way `var currentStatus = a.ReviewStatus;
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => a.ReviewStatus, new SelectList(a.ApplicationReviewStatusList, currentStatus), new { @class = "form -control", @style = "width:150px; height:30px" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => a.ReviewStatus, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })` but its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should go with IPagedList. It will surely do the trick. Since it has lots of features for bulk datas like :

1. Pagination for Huge amount of datas.
2. Styling is possible
3. And all about a Listing is done easily with Pagination.
4. And Lots of other features like Adding Css is possible, getting hidden values etc..